# Set cron job issue

Tags: cron

I am first time trying to set cron job in my linux server. I want to set every 10 mins my file will run.
The cron works fine but the problem is that the cron run as following

```
00:00 00:10 00:20
```

but i want it in this way

```
00:05 00:15 00:25
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have Vixie cron (the most common implementation these days), you can use this syntax:

```
5-55/10 * * * * command
```

where `5-55` specifies a range of minutes and `/10` says to run once every 10 minutes.

If not, just enumerate all the times you want it to run:

```
5,15,25,35,45,55 * * * * command
```

Running `man 5 crontab` should show you the documentation. (`man crontab` will show you the document for the `crontab` command; `man 5 crontab` describes the file format.)

Answer (score 1):

Reading the [manual page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?crontab%205) you need an entry in your crontab file such as

```
5,15,25,35,45,55 * * * * <script path>
```

Answer (score 1):

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/

Check out this link

Easy to remember format:

```
* * * * * command to be executed
- - - - -
| | | | |
| | | | ----- Day of week (0 - 7) (Sunday=0 or 7)
| | | ------- Month (1 - 12)
| | --------- Day of month (1 - 31)
| ----------- Hour (0 - 23)
------------- Minute (0 - 59)
```